# NSDate to NSString error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel, nsdateformatter

I am reciving 3 string values from my server that I put into a NSDictionary. I then pass those value into a **NSDateComponent** after which I try to create a **NSDateFormatter** which I am pretty sure is wrong.

The Date formate is supposed to be **01-April-2014** where the data I recive would look like this

```
{
 Day @"1"
 Month @"4"
 Year @"2014"
}
```

In the code below you will see I have tried to do this however I am having trouble in two area, the formatting of the **NSDateFormatter** and secondly how do I pass the date into an NSString so that I can display it in my label.

```
NSDateComponents *recivedDate = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[recivedDate setDay:[[recivedData objectForKey:@"Day"] intValue]];
[recivedDate setMonth:[[recivedData objectForKey:@"Month"] intValue]];
[recivedDate setYear:[[recivedData objectForKey:@"Year"] intValue]];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyy"];

NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:recivedDate];
dateResultLabel.text = dateString;
```

Comment: what will you get in recivedDate ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have bifurcated the date components alright, but you did not create an NSDate object from it.
Use

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:recivedDate];
```

and then use ur code to change it to string

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyy"];

NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
dateResultLabel.text = dateString;
```

ps: MMM should give you **April** instead of 04

Answer (score 0):

this may help you...

```
 NSDictionary *testDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[testDict setValue:@"14" forKey:@"Day"];
 [testDict setValue:@"4" forKey:@"Month"];
 [testDict setValue:@"2014" forKey:@"Year"];


NSString *str = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",[testDict objectForKey:@"Day"]] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",[testDict objectForKey:@"Month"]]] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[testDict objectForKey:@"Year"]]];





NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];


NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];


NSLog(@"%@",[formatter1 stringFromDate:[formatter dateFromString:str]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str_date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",[recivedData objectForKey:@"Day"],[recivedData objectForKey:@"Month"],[recivedData objectForKey:@"Year"]];

NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate* d = [df dateFromString:str_date];
NSLog(@"%@", d);
[df release];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMMM-yyyy"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:d];
NSLog(@"%@",stringFromDate);
[formatter release];

dateResultLabel.text = stringFromDate;
```